# npm install - jest doesn't exist in Azure Pipeline

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops

*Apologies in advance that I can't share source for this one:*

I've got a client that has to use Azure DevOps Pipelines to build a github enterprise hosted project.

It is a perfectly regular node.js project with jest specified as a devDependency in package.json.

When the `npm install` runs on an Azure Pipeline, jest doesn't get installed. I created a local x64 linux agent on Ubuntu 18 on my desktop, and it doesn't get installed their either **but** when I manually run `npm install` inside the /s/ directory it's all okay.

What is Azure Devops doing to the script that this is the result?

Comment: Hi @Billy Back Bedroom, it could work as expected when I run npm install in azure pipeline. I have shared some steps in the answer. You could check if it is similar with yours. If I missed key points, feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

> What is Azure Devops doing to the script that this is the result?

Test to run Npm install in Azure Pipeline and local machine, it seems that they have the same behavior. The Jest will be installed in `node_modules` folder.

Here are my steps, you could refer to it.

1. The File structure. I also add the jest to devDependency in package.json.

[image: File]

```
"devDependencies": {
"enzyme": "^3.3.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
"enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.3",
"jest": "^22.4.3"
}
```

2. Use the Npm install task in Azure Pipeline.

   ```
   - task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'npm install'
      inputs:
        workingDir: package
        verbose: false
   ```
3. Run the pipeline and the Jest will be installed in the node_modules folder.

[image: Result]

By the way, I  test the same steps on the `Microsoft-hosted agents: ubuntu-18.04` and it could work fine.

**Updates**

For running Npm install with the Script:

Here is an example:

```
steps:
- script: |
   cd $(build.sourcesdirectory)/package
    
   npm install 
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'
```

The first step is used to navigate to the source folder(contains package.json file).

Then the jest will be installed.

Comment: As I stated in the original question, I ran a local agent on Ubuntu in WSL and likewise it did not install jest. One difference I have noticed is that you use the NPM install task whereas I use a script task and just run "npm install" as a script. Could this be an issue?

Comment: @BillyBackBedroom  Yes ,this is a possible situation. If you use the script to run `Npm install` , you may need to navigate to the folder of the json file first. Could you try to use the `Npm install`  task directly? Please check if it could make some changes.

Comment: Hello @BillyBackBedroom. Do you have any update about this ticket?  If this issue still exist, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hi Kevin. This issue still exists, but we might have a chance this week to rewrite the pipeline and confirm our suspicions i.e. that using the node tasks works and using the script tasks does not. (apologies for the delay here)

Comment: Hi @BillyBackBedroom. Glad to know that the NPM task could give you some help. For  using script to run npm install, you need to navigate to the specified folder, then run NPM install script. You could check the update. If it could work, you may consider accepting it as answer.

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while and the project since ended. Your updated suggestion doesn't fix it. If you use the npm task, you get different results versus using a script task to run npm. Azure DevOps is a mess. The solution is to avoid the pipeline tools and write your own scripts - which is what we did in the end.